# How to install ACXMLAID as a service?

Tags: kofax

How to install Kofax - XML Importer as a service?

This will run as a service scanning C:\ACXMLAID\

Scan Folder > Read Xmls > Create Kofax Batches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this on Command Line:

[Kofax Install]\CaptureSS\ServLib\Bin

Run the command: ACXMLAI -install